# Direct PC-PC interconnection, parallel to main network

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, lan, gigabit-ethernet

My network is as follows:

Wifi-Router + DSL Modem, both in one device
several devices that use wi-fi, irrelevant for the question
PC A, connected to router via ethernet cable
PC B, connected to router via wi-fi

What I want to do is as follows:

I want to get an extra NIC card for PC-A and then connect PC-A and PC-B directly via high speed ethernet while also maintaining all of the functionality of the existing network

What do I have to do to configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible. Here are some tips:

- The computers need to be connected either through a router or via an
  [Ethernet crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).
- In the latter case, there will not be any DHCP server between PC A and B,
  so both computers on this trivial network need to have static IP addresses.
- Only the first network adapter on PC A should have a default gateway, not the
  second one, as only one default gateway is possible (two is a mess).
- If you wish PC B to get its Internet through PC A, you need in PC A
  to bridge its two network adapters into one (a random tutorial is
  [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10)).

Comment: If the Ethernet connection, as implied by the tags, is a gigabit connection the devices should be capable of [Auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface) in which case a crossover cable is unnecessary. With the point to point connection is can be necessary to use the IP for connections because Windows might still favor the Wi-Fi route, as it's the network with a router and potentially name resolution.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out on my own this morning. Came here to write the answer and saw your answer. Thanks anyway, what you wrote is pretty much exactly what I did.